# How to get only one group?

Tags: regex

I cannot write the regex that will:

- remove blank space/s
- remove characters (ae)
- only return ONE group of numbers and shall match number between 2000-4999

My pattern shall be in the below format:

```
"5. 282 ae"
```

I have tried the regex below, but it didn't work.

```
regex([2-4]\.\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\w\w)
```

Comment: right, maybe I should update that instead. My problem is that I get two groups instead of one

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: In your question you have 2 remove's, and 1 return you would like to do. What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In TextPad, this works:

Find what: `([2-4])\.\s+(\d\d\d)\s+ae`
Replace with: `$1$2`

This *does not* recognize `5. 282 ae`, however, because as you have specified, 5282 is not between 2000 and 4999.

It does replace `3. 278 ae` with `3278` and `4. 113 ae` with `4113`

You can try this out here:  http://fiddle.re/vt73v

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
/**
   <P>{@code java Regex2000To4999Xmpl}</P>
 **/
public class Regex2000To4999Xmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] XXX)  {

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([2-4])\\.\\s+(\\d\\d\\d)\\s+ae$");

      String sD1d2 = "$1$2";

      replace(p, "5. 282 ae", sD1d2);
      replace(p, "3. 278 ae", sD1d2);
      replace(p, "4. 113 ae", sD1d2);
   }
   public static final void replace(Pattern p_p, String s_findWhat, String s_replaceWith)  {
      System.out.println(p_p.matcher(s_findWhat).replaceFirst(s_replaceWith));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code]java Regex2000To4999Xmpl
5. 282 ae
3278
4113
```

Comment: I hope this has helped you. If it has, please consider choosing it as "the" answer, by clicking on the checkmark. Thank you!